# tsql script to add delete cascade to existing tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cascade, cascading-deletes

is there a script that can be used to enable cascaded deletion for existing tables.
Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE [wm].[TABLE_NAME]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TABLE_NAME_PARENT_TABLE_NAME] FOREIGN KEY([FOREIGN_KEY])
REFERENCES [wm].[PARENT_TABLE_NAME] ([PRIVATE_KEY])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

- `TABLE_NAME`: *name of the table where the children are stored.*
- `PARENT_TABLE_NAME`: *name of the table where the parents are stored.
  This placeholders can be equal*
- `FK_TABLE_NAME_PARENT_TABLE_NAME`: *just name for the constraint*
- `FOREIGN_KEY`: *field in the child table for the connection with the parents, `for example - ParentID`*
- `PRIMARY_KEY`: *field in the parents table, `for example - ID`*

---

```
ALTER TABLE [wm].[Thumbs]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Thumbs_Documents] FOREIGN KEY([DocID])
REFERENCES [wm].[Documents] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Comment: ok Thanks VMAtm looks good  but Im not sure what all  the plceholders mean

Comment: say I have 2 tables
Document
Thumbs
each thumb belongs to a document.
Can you dive me a concrete example using these tables?

Comment: TABLE_NAME - name of the table there the childs are stored.
PARENT_TABLE_NAME - name of the table there the parents are stored.
This placeholders can be equal

FK_TABLE_NAME_PARENT_TABLE_NAME - just name for the constraint

FOREIGN_KEY - field in the child table for the connection with the parents, for example - ParentID
PRIMARY_KEY - field in the parents table, for example - ID

Comment: I need the names for the ID of document in two your tables